# Move pdf files from subfolders to 1 main folder and re-use script for multiple folders

Tags: powershell

I have a quarterly returning process where around 60.000 pdf's are created. I unzip these to be able to determine the runtime of the creation of the pdf's. In total there are 7 different groups, so I have 7 set names. But the period is different, causing changes in folder name structure. The structure of the zipfiles contains subfolders which are used by other people, i want to move the pdf-files to 1 folder.

So situation:
M06-Q2_Juni will be M09-Q3_September

`Location: C:\Lolke\2020\M06-Q2_Juni\Run\PBNL\Digital (this contains subfolders)`

`Destination: C:\Lolke\2020\M06-Q2_Juni\Run\PBNL\allpdfs`

I have the below Test script that works when I hardcode source and destination, but this preferably is variable. But I cannot find anywhere on Google how to do this in combination with moving pdf files.

```
New-Item -Path '\\solon.prd\files\P\Global\Users\C43048\UserData\Desktop\Test_Powershell\allpdfs' -ItemType Directory
Get-Childitem \\solon.prd\files\P\Global\Users\C43048\UserData\Desktop\Test_Powershell\Digital -recurse -filter "*.pdf" | %{
                   Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination \\solon.prd\files\P\Global\Users\C43048\UserData\Desktop\Test_Powershell\allpdfs}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lolke,

I've generated a Function that will accept three parameters.

1. BasePath, the part of the path that is the same for both source and destination.
2. FilePath, the part need to locate the the PDF files.
3. Destination, the part to be added to the BasePath for the location where the PDFs are to be stored.

The program will create the Destination if it does not already exist.

I've commented the program so you can see what is going on.

```
Function Move-PDFs  {

 Param (
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
     [String]$BasePath,
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
     [String] $FilePath,
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
     [String] $Destination   
 )
 
   #Test to see if BasePath is valid
   If (-not (Test-Path -Path "$BasePath")){
     "Base Path: $BasePath does NOT exist!"
     Return ,$False
   } #End If

   #Test to see if BasePath+FilePath is valid
   If (-not (Test-Path -Path "$BasePath\$FilePath")) {
     "Full Path: $BasePath\$FilePath does NOT exist!"
     Return ,$False
   } #End If
   
   #Test to see if Destination is valid if not create it
   If (-not (Test-Path -Path "$BasePath\$Destination")) {
     "Destination Path: $BasePath\$Destination does NOT exist!"
     New-Item -Path "$BasePath\$Destination" -ItemType Directory
   } #End If
      
   #Get your PDF file list
   $GCIArgs = @{Path    = "$BasePath\$FilePath"
                Include = "*.PDF"
                Recurse = $True}
   $FileList = Get-ChildItem @GCIArgs
   
   #Copy the files
   ForEach ($File in $FileList) {
      Copy-Item -Path "$File" -Destination "$BasePath\$Destination" }
   
} #End Function Move-PDFs

#Call the function Using My Test data.
$MPArgs = @{BasePath = "G:\Test\WPOA Files"
            FilePath = "Digital"
            Destination = "AllPDFS"}
Move-PDFs @MPArgs
```

Of course since you have several locations you can easily add an array containing the BasePaths and then loop through the array and make the call to Move-PDFs. This assumes that the FilePath and Destination don't change. That can be handled but it's a little more work.

If desired more testing can be added, you could also pass back the number of files copied, and you could include the Force parameter on the copy-item just in case two file have the same name.

This base program should give you a good start.

EDIT: I just realized that I misnamed the routine or misunderstood your requirements. The program as written COPIES the files it doesn't Move them. If you want to move the file change the Copy-Item to Move-Item. If you want to copy them you might want to change the name to Copy-PDFs.

HTH